# Should undersink Reverse Osmosis be installed in a leased condominium?

Tags: water-filtration

Assumption 1. My aunt knows nothing of repair or maintenance or trade work.

2. She must not change or transform the structure and interior of the condominium in Canada that she is leasing.
3. Tap water in Canada is normally safe, but  my aunt needs Reverse Osmosis (hereafter RO) water for health reasons.
4. [APEC](http://www.freedrinkingwater.com/ro-counter-detail.htm) and [Aquasana](http://www.aquasana.com/drinking-water-filter-systems) have both installed/undersink (hooked to water pipes) and portable (countertop) RO systems, but her first choice is the former that purify more.

Subject to the above assumptions, about an undersink RO system:

5. Is it possible to install it?
6. Even if so, can she remove and take away it, after the lease's end?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a do-it-yourself home improvement question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a picture of under the sink, it's hard to say if your aunt has room for an undersink RO system or how hard it'd be to install (and subsequently, uninstall). Even in the simplest case, with plenty of room and updated plumbing, RO systems need a supply line, a waste line, and a faucet, all of which a plumber would have to connect to the existing plumbing. Removing all of that when she leaves will be just as much work. Plus, if you had to install a new faucet, that may have required irreversibly modifying the sink or counter-top.

In any case, I really don't think your aunt shouldn't be doing any of this without permission from the landlord. If the plumbing fails and causes damage to the unit or other units, and it's traced back to the unauthorized changes, she could be in real trouble (disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer; that just seems like common sense). You might suggest your aunt talk to her landlord and see if they'll split the cost of installing a RO unit, in exchange for leaving it when she leaves.

Otherwise, I'd say go the counter-top route.